# Write C function that returns int to Fortran

Tags: c, gcc, fortran, ipc, gfortran

Ultimately I am trying to write an IPC calculator making use of Fortran to calculate and C to pass the data between the two Fortran programs. When I am done it will hopefully look like:

```
Fortran program to pass input -> Client written in C -> Server written in C -> Fortran program to calculate input and pass ans back
```

The C client/server part is done, but at the moment I am stuck trying to write a program that takes input in a Fortran program, passes it to a C program that calculates the answer. However, I see som weird behavior.

Fortran program

```
program calculator
    !implicit none

    ! type declaration statements
    integer x
    x = 1

    ! executable statements
    x = calc(1,1)
    print *, x

end program calculator
```

C function

```
int calc_(int *a, int *b ) {
    return *a+*b;
}
```

I have written a main program that verifies that int calc_() does indeed return 2 when called as calc_(1,1) in C, but when I run the program I get the output from Fortran.

I am using this makefile
    # Use gcc for C and gfortran for Fortran code.
    CC=gcc
    FC=gfortran

```
calc : calcf.o calcc.o
    $(FC) -o calc calcf.o calcc.o

calcc.o : calcc.c
    $(CC) -Wall -c calcc.c

calcf.o: calcf.f90
    $(FC) -c calcf.f90
```

I cannot for the world figure out why this is the case, and it's driving me mad.

Comment: Why have you got `implicit none` commented out?  If it wasn't commented out the compiler would have told you what the problem was!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Almost embarrassingly simple. You must declare calc as an integer in Fortran. The working Fortran code is thus

```
program calculator
    !implicit none

    ! type declaration statements
    integer x, calc
    x = 1

    ! executable statements
    x = calc(1,1)
    print *, x

end program calculator
```

Comment: Consider using the ISO-C-Binding for compatibility.

Comment: @haraldkl, what is this used for?

Comment: The ISO-C-Binding provides a portable way to interact with C. It takes for example care of symbol names and provides datatypes to ensure interoperability of the data handed from one side to the other.

Comment: I will look into this. Thank you.