# Invoke a client-program written in C, from Fortran 90

Tags: c, fortran, ipc

*This is in sort a followup question to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37888128/write-c-function-that-returns-int-to-fortran).*

I am trying to invoke a client, written in C, from the Fortran 90 program seen below.

```
program name
implicit none

    ! type declaration statements
    character indata, ipaddr, ans, calc
    integer portno
    indata = "INDATA"
    ipaddr = "localhost"
    portno = 55555

    ! executable statements
    print *, indata
    ans = calc(indata, ipaddr, portno)
    print *, ans

end program name
```

My C program looks as follows

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <netdb.h> 


/*
int main()
{
    calc_("1 2 add", "localhost", 55555);
    return 0;
}
*/

void error(char *msg)
{
    perror(msg);
    exit(0);
}

int calc_(char *indata, char *ipaddr, int *in_portno)
{
    int sockfd, portno, n;

    struct sockaddr_in serv_addr;
    struct hostent *server;

    char buffer[256];
    portno = in_portno;
    sockfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
    if (sockfd < 0) 
        error("ERROR opening socket");

    server = gethostbyname(ipaddr);
    if (server == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr,"ERROR, no such host\n");
        exit(0);
    }

    memset(((char *) &serv_addr), 0, (sizeof(serv_addr)));
    serv_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    memcpy(((char *)server->h_addr),
           ((char *)&serv_addr.sin_addr.s_addr),
           (server->h_length));
    serv_addr.sin_port = htons(portno);

    if (connect(sockfd,(struct sockaddr *)&serv_addr,sizeof(serv_addr)) < 0) 
        error("ERROR connecting");

    memset((buffer), 0, (256));
    strcpy(buffer, indata);    
    //fgets(buffer, 255, *indata);
    n = write(sockfd, buffer, strlen(buffer));
    if (n < 0) 
         error("ERROR writing to socket");
    memset((buffer), 0, (256));
    n = read(sockfd,buffer,255);
    if (n < 0) 
         error("ERROR reading from socket");
    printf("%s\n",buffer);
    return 0;
}
```

In the C program there is an out commented main program. If main is used, everything works just fine (the server running on localhost replies: 3, which is expected), but when I try to run the programs as seen above, using the makefile:

```
# Use gcc for C and gfortran for Fortran code.
CC=gcc
FC=gfortran

calc : calcf.o fclient.o
    $(FC) -o calc calcf.o fclient.o

fclient.o : fclient.c
    $(CC) -Wall -c fclient.c

calcf.o: calcf.f90
    $(FC) -c calcf.f90
```

I get the following error message printed to stdout.

```
 1 //[author's comment], this 1 is from the "1 2 add" printed in the .f90 program

Program received signal SIGSEGV: Segmentation fault - invalid memory reference.

Backtrace for this error:
#0  0x7fd8e9c9430f in ???
#1  0x7fd8e9d6816f in ???
#2  0x7fd8e9d59677 in ???
#3  0x400e0a in ???
#4  0x400cdd in ???
#5  0x400d81 in ???
#6  0x7fd8e9c81740 in ???
#7  0x400b68 in ???
#8  0xffffffffffffffff in ???
zsh: segmentation fault (core dumped)  ./calc
```

I am able to understand that I am in some way accessing *restricted* memory, or memory that the program should not tinker with, but I am unable to see where this is happening and why it is only the case when I call `calc_` from the .f90-program.

Comment: First, build your c program into an executable, then execute: _[Execute_Command_Line ( Command, Wait, Exitstat, Cmdstat, Cmdmsg )](https://software.intel.com/en-us/forums/intel-visual-fortran-compiler-for-windows/topic/515947)_ from FORTRAN

Comment: What little I ever knew about Fortran I have forgotten by now (and was about Fortran 77), but I tried your program, and when it came to `calc_` the parameters had very strange values. So my guess is that this is some sort of parameter passing problem.

Comment: @ryyker, Ultimately, I want to be able to specify the indata in the fortran program and then have the client/server programs simply pass the data along to another Fortran program that does some work on the data. As for know, this is not possible, and execute_command_line seems not to be the way to go.

Comment: Did you declare the calc routine with CDECL?

Comment: Fortran `CHARACTER` and C `char *` are likely not compatible with each other; when I did something like this *many* years ago on a VMS system, I had to use a "descriptor" type in the C code (basically, a struct containing the base address of the string and its length).  I wouldn't be surprised if that was an issue here.

Comment: If you comment out main(), how do you know that the C compiler creates any code at all? That is, how do you know `calc_` exists if it isn't referenced by the C code? Please look at the disassembly of the C code, you should have some hundred instructions or so.

Comment: The answers suggest using the C interop facilities of Fortran 2003 --  Stackoverflow has a tag that will show you questions with many examples of using this facility: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/fortran-iso-c-binding

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Prior to the C interop facilities introduced in Fortran 2003, calling an external C function from Fortran required tricks specific to the target environment and the compilers involved.  Moreover, if the C function in question was not designed specifically to be callable by code such as is generated by the Fortran compiler involved, then it was usually necessary to write a wrapper function (in C) to bridge the gap.

The main issues to be overcome are

- ***name mangling***: the name by which a function is referenced in Fortran source code often differs from the one the linker must link.  Often one or more additional underscores are introduced, and typically the function name is put into a standard case (often lowercase, but some compilers have used uppercase).
- ***argument types***: some Fortran argument types simply cannot be passed cleanly, at least not without detailed knowledge of the relevant Fortran implementation.  Assumed-shape arrays, array sections, and arrays with `allocatable` or `pointer` attributes are typically problematic.
- ***representation of types***: the biggest one here is array index order.  Fortran arrays are indexed in column-major order, whereas C arrays are indexed in row-major order.  This isn't necessarily a problem for *passing* arrays (but see also above); rather it presents a problem for using them correctly on one side and the other of the call.  Another biggie here is that Fortran `character` objects (strings) are not null-terminated.  Instead, each has a fixed length that is included in the value representation.  This is usually accommodated at a C function interface by passing two actual arguments, a pointer to the start of the `char` array and a length, but other forms have been used as well.
- ***function call semantics***: Fortran passes all arguments by reference.  That usually presents as a C function interface where the arguments are all pointers, with the exception that the string-length parameters described above (because Fortran `character` objects have *fixed* width).
- ***argument order***: a Fortran-callable C function will normally use the same argument order as it expects to be used by the Fortran-side call, but that's not guaranteed, and anyway the string-length arguments don't fit cleanly into that.  Some Fortran compilers pass them immediately after the corresponding pointer; others group all the string length arguments at the end of the argument list.  (And of course, that doesn't consider those that use an altogether different mechanism to represent string arguments.)

It's conceivable that I've overlooked something.

Pretty much all of that has substantial implementation dependencies, but people have nevertheless been calling back and forth between Fortran and C since well before Fortran 90 was conceived, and they continue to do it.  If you do not have the benefit of standardized C interop to rely upon, then you need to know some details of how your Fortran compiler generates code. There are various automated facilities for that, including in GNU Autoconf, or you can just consult the docs or even experiment.

For what it's worth, you appear to have several problems, some in the areas described above, and some entirely in the Fortran part.  Especially notable in the Fortran part is that you do not declare lengths for your `character` variables, so they all get the default length (1).  That's evidently not what you want.  At the function call, you are also being tripped up by Fortran not using null-terminated strings and by it passing extra arguments for the string lengths.

But Fortran 2003 is now thirteen years old, and the C interop bits are widely implemented, including in `gfortran`, which your Makefile reveals to be your Fortran implementation.  The `gfortran` docs cover [C interop](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gfortran/Interoperability-with-C.html) fairly thoroughly.  There is too much for this already-lengthy answer, but key points include:

- Write the C part in natural C.
- Use the [`ISO_C_BINDING`](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gfortran/ISO_005fC_005fBINDING.html#ISO_005fC_005fBINDING) module.
- Write a Fortran `interface` to the C function, defining formal argument and return types appropriately, including with appropriate `kind` attributes (drawn from values provided as parameters by `ISO_C_BINDING`)
- Apply the `bind(C)` attribute to symbols that must be interoperable with C

Answer (score 3):

Here's something from the [GNU `gfortran` documentation](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gfortran/Interoperable-Subroutines-and-Functions.html):

> Strings are handled quite differently in C and Fortran. In C a string is a NUL-terminated array of characters while in Fortran each string has a length associated with it and is thus not terminated (by e.g. NUL). For example, if one wants to use the following C function,
>
> ```
>        #include <stdio.h>
>        void print_C(char *string) /* equivalent: char string[]  */
>        {
>           printf("%s\n", string);
>        }
> ```
>
> to print “Hello World” from Fortran, one can call it using
>
> ```
>        use iso_c_binding, only: C_CHAR, C_NULL_CHAR
>        interface
>          subroutine print_c(string) bind(C, name="print_C")
>            use iso_c_binding, only: c_char
>            character(kind=c_char) :: string(*)
>          end subroutine print_c
>        end interface
>        call print_c(C_CHAR_"Hello World"//C_NULL_CHAR)
> ```
>
> As the example shows, one needs to ensure that the string is NUL terminated. Additionally, the dummy argument *string* of `print_C` is a length-one assumed-size array; using character(len=*) is not allowed. The example above uses `c_char_"Hello World"` to ensure the string literal has the right type; typically the default character kind and `c_char` are the same and thus "Hello World" is equivalent. However, the standard does not guarantee this.

Comment: Thank you. I have read this though, and I am unable to see the use of the interface. It seems like it is superfluous, or? I did some tests earlier (as can be seen in the link I gave in my original post) and was able to call a C function without issues. What is the interface for?

Comment: The interface makes sure that *string* data is passed correctly from Fortran to C code.  Like the referenced document points out, Fortran and C treat string data *very* differently; Fortran does not use 0-terminated strings, and explicitly stores the length metadata as part of the string.  You can't just pass a Fortran string to a C function like you can an integer or float.

Comment: And nothing ensures that the order of parameters between Fortran and C are the same. In old compilers they were passed in reverse order. That's what the interface guarantees: calling conventions are correctly used.

Comment: It's possible you may find the module at http://fortranwiki.org/fortran/show/c_interface_module useful in working with string/char arrays between C and fortran